# In rspec, can I make sure certain examples run only if another example passes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I'm wondering if it is possible to make certain example tests run if and only if another passes? I know that you can filter examples with `if: something` metadata, but from what I understand, `something` cannot be set within an example because examples operate as object instances, while declarations of the example (where `if: something` would be) operate in the class methods of the examplegroups (someone else can probably example this better than me).

In code, this is what I'm looking for, or something similar

```
describe Something do

  it "has a breadcrumb trail" do
    expect(page).to have_breadcrumb
    has_breadcrumb = true
  end
  it "has the parent name in the breadcrumb", if: has_breadcrumb do
    expect(page).to have_text("somename")
  end
end
```

Obviously simplified here, but the motivation is that I want to be able to setup tests where the expectation relies on the implementation of another feature.

Rspec 2.12

Comment: The standard practice is to just mark the specs for not-yet-implemented features as `pending`.

Comment: My idea that could be answered with this question is when testing views. There is a test to see if a form exists. Then, afterwards, there is a test for each field that should be inside the form. If the test for the form field fails, I don't want to see if the fields inside the form are there. This would give less failure output and would be easier to pinpoint problems.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for tests is making sure that your tests are independent of each other. I'm not sure what you are trying to do is ideal.

Comment: I don't think it's about independence. Let's continue with the example I've given. The breadcrumb is a feature of many different types of pages, letting the user know what the parents / grandparents the page has. On a certain page I want to test that the breadcrumb is appearing, this is one test. Let's say I delete a page (a different, indepedent test) and want to make sure that the page that it is redirected to has the correct parents. The only way to do this is through the breadcrumb feature, which may or may not have been implemented. I think I will go with Dmitry's comment. cheers though.